# Sqlalchemy bulk insert with Pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have an object that I need to insert several times using loop. Every loop iteration I change  some fields values.
My code is:

```
@view_config(route_name="be.bautocredits.rates.add",
             request_method="POST",
             permission="admin",
             renderer="json")
def _add_rates(self):
    _ = self.request.translate
    controls = self.request.POST.items()
    schema = AutocreditRateSchema()
    try:
        schema.deserialize(controls)
        rate = AutocreditRate()
        rate.autocredit = Autocredit.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_autocredits_rid'))
        rate.carshow = Carshow.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_carshows_rid'))
        rate.currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_currencies_rid'))
        rate.min_cost_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('min_cost_currencies_rid'))
        rate.max_cost_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('max_cost_currencies_rid'))
        rate.min_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('min_currencies_rid'))
        rate.max_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('max_currencies_rid'))
        rate.manufacturer = Manufacturer.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_manufacturers_rid'))
        rate.autocredit.updated = datetime.datetime.now()

        _cars_rids = list(set(self.request.POST.getall('_cars_rid')))
        if _cars_rids:
            for _cars_rid in _cars_rids:
                rate.car = Car.by_rid(_cars_rid)
                DBSession.add(rate)
        else:
            DBSession.add(rate)

    except colander.Invalid, e:
        return dict(errors=dict(e.asdict().items()+dict(status_bar=_(u'Check errors')).items()))
    return dict()
```

This code inserts only single row. For some reasons I can't set loop directly in "try block" begins.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`DBSession.add` adds an object to session (as the name implies) - at that time no SQL queries are emitted, `.add` just makes the session aware of the object.

You can continue to modify the object's properties until the session is committed - regardless of how many times you've added the object to the session only one row will be added to the database.

You *may* be able to do what you're trying to do with some clever session flushing, but, seriously, why not just create a separate object for each row? That's how ORMs work in general.

```
def _add_rates(self):
    _ = self.request.translate
    controls = self.request.POST.items()
    schema = AutocreditRateSchema()
    try:
        schema.deserialize(controls)
        _cars_rids = list(set(self.request.POST.getall('_cars_rid')))
        autocredit = Autocredit.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_autocredits_rid'))
        carshow = Carshow.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_carshows_rid'))
        currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_currencies_rid'))
        min_cost_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('min_cost_currencies_rid'))
        max_cost_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('max_cost_currencies_rid'))
        min_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('min_currencies_rid'))
        max_currency = Currency.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('max_currencies_rid'))
        manufacturer = Manufacturer.by_rid(self.request.POST.get('_manufacturers_rid'))
        if _cars_rids:
            for _cars_rid in _cars_rids:
                rate = AutocreditRate(autocredit=autocredit, carshow=carshow, ...)
                rate.car = Car.by_rid(_cars_rid)
                rate.autocredit.updated = datetime.datetime.now()
                DBSession.add(rate)
        else:
            rate = AutocreditRate(autocredit=autocredit, carshow=carshow, ...)
            rate.autocredit.updated = datetime.datetime.now()
            DBSession.add(rate)
```